# Access 2010, Input Filename with added text at end

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a text string which is the filepath followed by filename.
Here is an example:
\server\folder\subfolder\OUTPUT\filename_05272015.xlsx
filename could also be this:
\server\folder\subfolder\OUTPUT\filename2_05272015.xlsx

What I am trying to accomplish is this: take current filename based on what user selected as "Input" and output will be that filename with _Modified.xlsx on the end.

These filenames are Dim'd in my VB

```
 Dim CurrentFile as string
 Dim strPath as string
   CurrentFile = Mid(me.Text1,34,18)
   strPath = Me.OutputFolderText & "\" & CurrentFile & "_Modified.xlsx"
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "qry_MyQuery", strPath
```

Problem is the output filename looks like this:

filename2_05272015_Modified.xlsx
and then

filename_05272015._Modified.xlsx where there is a "." after the MMDDYYYY

I am trying to figure out how to get all variations to have an accurate output filename _05272015_modified.xlsx

The text before the _MMDDYYYY may change.  _MMDDYYYY_Modified.xlsx will always be on the end of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Ah VBA. Can you try this instead?

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CurrentFile = fso.GetFileName(me.Text1)
```

Comment: I am getting a Compile error:  Method or data member not found

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this.  Not sure if this was the best method or not

```
 CurrentFile = Mid(Left(Me.Text1, InStr(Me.Text1, ".") - 1), 34,  18)
```